# Manimlib Axes has no attribute 'add_coordinates'

Tags: python, animation, math, manim

I'm learning to use Manim by 3blue1brown and it's really cool. I'm following some tutorials online to get the ropes but I'm running into a problem

```
from manimlib import *
import numpy as np

class Anim4 (Scene):

def construct(self):

    axes = Axes(x_range = [0, 5, 1], y_range= [0, 3, 1],
    x_length= 5, y_length=3,
    axis_config = {"include tip": True, "numbers_to_exclude": [0]}
    ).add_coordinates()
    axes.to_edge(UR)
    axis_labels = axes.get_axis_labels(x_label = "x", y_label = "f(x)")

    graph = axes.get_graph(lambda x : x**0.5, x_range = [0, 4], color = 
    YELLOW)
    graphing_stuff = VGroup(axes, graph, axis_labels)

    self.play(DrawBorderThenFill(axes), Write(axis_labels))
    self.play(Create(graph))
    self.play(graphing_stuff.animate.shift(DOWN*4))
    self.play(axes.animate.shift(LEFT*3), RUN_TIME = 3)
```

2 Problems. It isn't recognising the Create function, it shows an error saying:

> Axes object has no attribute 'add_coordinates'

I have no idea what's going wrong.

[Youtube video I was following](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jFqYq9quBds)

Was there a change in code or something I'm not aware of? Do these functions even exist anymore?

Comment: What is the full error message? I assume it's made of several lines and states which lines from your code started the error? What does "It isn't recognising the Create function" mean?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you copy a code that is using manim library and you are importing manimlib (manim and manimlib are not compatible with each other). You can install that version of manim and do not use manimlib or you can change the functions to the ones that are in manimlib.

```
from manimlib import *
import numpy as np

class Anim4 (Scene):

    def construct(self):

        axes = Axes((-5, 5), (-1, 9))
        axes.add_coordinate_labels() #change axes.add_coordinate for axes.add_coordinate_labels
        axes.to_edge(UR)
        axes.add(axes.get_axis_labels(x_label_tex="x",y_label_tex="f(x)")) #add "axes.add"


        graph = axes.get_graph(lambda x : x**0.5, x_range = [0, 4], color = 
        YELLOW)
        graphing_stuff = VGroup(axes, graph)

        self.play(DrawBorderThenFill(axes))
        self.play(ShowCreation(graph)) # Change "Create" for "ShowCreation"
        self.play(graphing_stuff.animate.shift(DOWN*4))
        self.play(axes.animate.shift(LEFT*3), RUN_TIME = 3)
```

Comment: replace this part of the code 


`self.play(graphing_stuff.animate.shift(DOWN*4))
        self.play(axes.animate.shift(LEFT*3), RUN_TIME = 3)`

Comment: with this so you get the graph in the middle of the camera

`self.play(graphing_stuff.animate.scale(50/100))
        self.play(graphing_stuff.animate.shift(DOWN*2))
        self.wait()
        self.play(graphing_stuff.animate.shift(LEFT*3), RUN_TIME = 3)
        self.wait()
        self.play(graphing_stuff.animate.shift(UP*2).shift(RIGHT*3).scale(100/50))`